# php timeout (pause time) in a loop

Tags: php, loops, timeout, sleep

I'm trying to figure out how to pause a loop in php so it executes once every 5 minutes for example

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //send email to a member
   // pause for a minute then continue the loop
}
```

simple example

```
for($x=0;$x<=4;$x++){
  echo $x."<br>";
  sleep(5);
  // the loop will be delayed for 25 seconds then it'll print 5 lines at once
}
```

Comment: The loop is a part of the whole script, so of course pausing the loop will pause the whole script.... if you want something to run very 5 minutes, use a cron job

Comment: I don't want to use a cron jop I need to pause this loop for 5 minutes then resume it

Comment: The cron jop will be executed every while I know but it'll execute the whole loop and it'll send many emails at once without pausing or delaying

Comment: A cron job can be set up to work as you want it to work..... if you want it to send only 1 email each time it executes then you can write it to do that.... but you can't sleep in loop being executed from an http request without sleeping thatrequest as well

Comment: Not if you set up a send queue and only fetch x amount of emails at every request

Comment: If you don't want to do it as a cron job, you can write it as a daemon, that's permanently running in the background; but that's a lot harder to deal with because you have to ensure that it restarts if it falls over

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: works with mail but not with a simple loop as i described in the question

Answer (score 0):

This script works as you expect. Every iteration of the loop is being delayed 5 seconds. However, what you are seeing is the output sent to the browser, which is buffered and delivered by PHP at certain times (normally when the script execution finishes).

You can try playing with `ob_get_contents()` to retrieve the output buffer on each iteration.

PHP Manual: [ob_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-contents.php)

Please note that you may well exceed the `max_execution_time` with this approach. A cron job is definitely the way forward. Or you can leave the browser open and force a refresh every 5 minutes (not practical).